# How I can split multiple Quotation mark from this below string

Tags: java, sql

How I can split multiple quotation marks from this string? please help me, my project stuck here because of this.

```
strLine1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Header Perceived Severity="":Friendly Name="":Alarm Type="":Specific Problems="":Event Date and Time="":Clearing Status="":Clearing Time="";");
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question, it is unclear

Comment: your statement generate compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

You code won't comiple:

```
strLine1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Header Perceived Severity="":Friendly Name="":
    Alarm Type="":Specific Problems="":Event Date and Time="":
    Clearing Status="":Clearing Time="");
```

1. missed the closing brackets in the end.
2. you need to escape quotations
3. add one more quotation in the end

.

```
strLine1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Header Perceived Severity=\"\":Friendly Name=\"\":
    Alarm Type=\"\":Specific Problems=\"\":Event Date and Time=\"\":
    Clearing Status=\"\":Clearing Time=\"\"");
```